# How to add member to the group which doesn't have username?

Tags: telegram, telegram-group

In Telegram IM client, normally when I add members to my group, I type their username in the box and it's displayed on the list. However some users don't have a username, so they aren't listed when typed by their name, therefore I can't add them.

Is it by design, or there is any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- by username
- contact / number
- by ID

> **Q: How do I add more members? What's an invite link?**
>
> You can add your contacts, or using search by username.
>
> It is easy to migrate existing groups to Telegram by sending people an invite link. To create an invite link, go to Group Info — Add Member — Invite to Group via Link.
>
> Anyone who has Telegram installed will be able to join your group by following this link. If you choose to revoke the link, it will stop working immediately.

- **[https://telegram.org/faq#q](https://telegram.org/faq#q-how-do-i-add-more-members-what-39s-an-invite-link)**

Comment: What's ID? ....

Comment: @kenorb https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLZqOmx8pl8